# which is the right apply for two numeric matrices?

Tags: r, apply

Say I have a vector of 1000 `x` observations, and a vector of 1000 `y` observations. Each row of `x` and each row of `y` correspond to 100 samples respectively.

```
x <- t(replicate(1000, rnorm(100,mean=6)))
y <- t(replicate(1000, rnorm(100,mean=5)))
```

I would like to conduct a t.test to see whether the mean of each row of `x` was significantly different than the mean of each row of `y`.

Which is the right `apply` to use in this context? Ideally, it would be something like:

```
Xapply(x,y, function(x,y) t.test(x,y)$conf.int)
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6):

**1) mapply** Try this. `dt_` converts each of `x` and `y` into a data frame of the original rows which is also a list of the original rows allowing `mapply` to be used directly. You may or may not want the outer `t` shown depending on the output orientation desired:

```
dt_ <- function(x) data.frame(t(x))
conf.int.1 <- t(mapply(function(x, y) t.test(x, y)$conf.int, dt_(x), dt_(y)))
```

**1a)** slightly shorter variation using formula notation for the function.  See info on `fn` on the [gsubfn home page](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) and in the [package documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gsubfn) for more

```
library(gsubfn) # fn
conf.int.1a <- t(fn$mapply(~ t.test(x, y)$conf.int, dt_(x), dt_(y)))
```

**2) apply** Another method is to create a 3d array from `x` and `y` and then apply the t test over the first dimenstion:

```
z <- array(c(x, y), c(dim(x), 2))
conf.int.2 <- t(apply(z, 1, function(x) t.test(x[, 1], x[, 2])$conf.int))
```

**2a)** A slightly nicer way of creating the 3d array can be implemented using `abind` in the [abind](http://cran.r-project.org/package=abind) package:

```
library(abind)
a <- abind(x, y, along = 3)
conf.int.2a <- t(apply(a, 1, function(x) t.test(x[, 1], x[, 2])$conf.int))
```

UPDATE: Added solution 2.

UPDATE: Added solution 2a.

Comment: thanks. are there any performance concerns regarding `mapply`? i ask mainly because i've heard that certain `apply`-s aren't actually very efficient, and this is a toy example; in real life there might be a lot more than 1000 experiments to test.

Comment: You didn't previously ask about performance ...  the example you gave probably runs almost instantaneously with any of the approaches suggested here.  If you're worried about performance you might edit your question to specify how big your real problem is ... the `rbenchmark` and `microbenchmark` packages are useful.

Comment: Not in a generic sense. For this particular problem you will need to do benchmarking if the performance is important.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to cbind them and run an ordinary apply on the larger object:

```
 apply( cbind(x,y), 1 , function(x) t.test(x[1:100], x[101:200] )$conf.int)
```

Comment: I think as written you might have to convert the matrix to a data frame, or use `x[1:100,]` and `y[101:200,]`  ...?

Comment: I don't think so. When the "cbound" object hits the anonymous function it is a length 200 vector named "x".

Answer (score 3):

You can combine both matrices and create a factor vector for a formula used in `t.test`:

```
fac <- gl(2, ncol(x)) # factor
apply(cbind(x, y), 1, function(x) t.test(x ~ fac)$conf.int)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(101)
x <- t(replicate(1000, rnorm(100,mean=6)))
y <- t(replicate(1000, rnorm(100,mean=5)))
```

A `for` loop would actually be fine here, but you can use `sapply` on the indices:

```
 result <- t(sapply(seq(nrow(x)),
             function(i) t.test(x[i,],y[i,])$conf.int))
```

Alternatively (probably slightly less efficiently) you can turn `x` and `y` into lists and use `mapply`:

```
 xList <- split(x,row(x))
 yList <- split(y,row(y))
 m1 <- mapply(t.test,xList,yList,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
 result2 <- t(sapply(m1,"[[","conf.int"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `mapply`:

```
t(mapply(function(i,j)t.test(x[i,],y[j,])$conf.int,
      seq(nrow(x)),seq(nrow(y))))
```